# wordpress woocommerce: how to display product custom attribute on category page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

i am using woocommerce theme. created some products with custom attribute  **Qun**

i want to display **Qun** on ca tegorypage below the product image.

```
 is there any solution for that? have a look at the attached image.

 i want to display that custom attribute on category page.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use while loop like this

```
if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  $key_1_values = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Qun' );

   // check if the custom field has a value
  if( ! empty( $key_1_value ) ) {
     echo $key_1_value;
   } 

  }
}
```

Comment: where do i add this? in which file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = array_shift(woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->id, 'attr/cate_name', 'names'));
```

Comment: where do i add this? in which file?

Comment: where do i place $result = array_shift(woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->id, 'attr/cate_name', 'names'));   code?  in which file?